# Find next month

Tags: linear-algebra, poisson-distribution

I have a man that sells in average 36 deal papers every year.I am searching the possibility to sell more than 2 deal papers,in the next mouth.
I take this and solve it
$$
    f(x)={n \choose x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x}
$$
`For n=36 x=2  p=30` (from months)
I solve it and i find 4 is this right?A friend of me told me it isn't Dionymic nor Poisson

Comment: You have to know which distribution this is. Otherwise, you can only get bounds, no exact value.

Comment: how can i know?it confuses me the next mouth ..

Comment: I would assume that the correct distribution here to use is poisson.  It certainly isn't likely to be binomial like your attempt is.  And, "I solve it and I find 4"  Surely you aren't thinking that $4$ is the correct answer to a *probability* question...

Comment: wow really?could you explain me why it is Poisson?

Comment: Because it seems plausible that the man might have sold a number of papers different than $36$ in the year.  If he gets particularly lucky, maybe he sold 50 papers.  Maybe if he got particularly unlucky he only sold five papers total in a year.  It seems plausible that if the right bit of luck occurs that he sells any number of papers in the year from $0,1,2,3,\dots$ on up into the trillions.  Granted... in reality he won't be selling billions of papers, there wouldn't be enough resources or people to sell to... but the point is that he isn't guaranteed to sell exactly $36$ next year.

Comment: Further, it seems plausible to assume that his sales of papers might occur relatively spread out and when each paper gets sold would be relatively independent from one another.  The sale of one paper shouldn't influence the others.  Maybe he sold two papers in the same day, maybe he sold none this month at all, etc... Trying to model such a situation is *exactly* what the poisson distribution is used for.  Read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).  Granted, in reality maybe people are more likely to buy papers more often in May, that is why it an assumption

Comment: As for your attempt... $f(x)=\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$ is the pdf for a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), $p$ would be representative of a probability, and probabilities are always somewhere between $0$ and $1$., so setting $p=30$ is horribly wrong and makes no sense in the given context.  The formula $\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$ gives the probability that within $n$ independent repetitions of the same task where probability of success is $p$, exactly $x$ of the attempts were successes.

Comment: thank you a lot man,if you could answer just to credit you i mean to press the tick cause you explain it a lot and you worth it